# No bijective function $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_+$ is a polynomial

Tags: functions

I was thinking the following: There are bijections $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_+$. How can I prove that none of the bijections can a polynomial with real coefficients? I was thinking that the polynomial degree must be even to make sure the values are always positive. Zero polynomial is clearly not a solution. But if the degree is at least two, how can we conclude that the polynomial starts to grow too fast to be a bijective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said $f$ will grow too fast if it's not linear. Indeed, let $f(x) = a_nx^n + \dots + a_0$ where $n$ is even. You can write $f(x) = x^n(a_n + a_{n-1}x^{-1} + \dots ) = x^ng(x)$. Now $g(x)$ is bounded on $[1, \infty)$, so there is $C > 0$ with $|g(x)| \leq C$ and $|f(x)| > a_n(x^n - C)$. This means that $f$ can't be bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$? The only polynomials with inverses over the integers are a+x and a-x; if the degree is greater than 1, then eventually the highest order term will dominate, and the function will be monotonic on the tails. So once it skips an integer, it can't come back to it. If the order is 1, then slope has to be an integer (otherwise the range wouldn't be integers). But the slope of its inverse also has to be an integer, and the slope of the inverse is the reciprocal of the slope of the original. The only integers whose reciprocals are integers are 1 and -1.

Over the reals, if the degree is odd, then (lim x -> -inf) = -inf, so its range isn't $\mathbb Z_+$. If its degree is even, then (lim x -> inf) = (lim x -> -inf) = inf, so it can't be a bijection.

Comment: The argument with the limit make non sense. For example, $f(k) = 2k$ if $k \geq 0$ and $f(-k) = -2k + 1$ if $k < 0$ verify that $\lim f(x) = \infty$ both when $x \to - \infty$ and $x \to \infty$ but $f$ is injective.

Comment: It's your comment that doesn't make sense. You've giving two different functions. If you intended to present a piecewise-defined function, then that's not a polynomial. I suppose that there are even-degree polynomials that are injective over the integers, but not over the reals. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I know that the OP was talking about polynomial but it's unclear how you can apply this limit argument, even if we restrict to polynomial functions.

Comment: Given x0, we can without loss of generality assume that f(x0) > f(-x0). If (lim x->-inf) = inf, then there exists x1<x0 such that f(x1) > f(x0). Since f is a polynomial, it's continuous, so there is some x2 between x1 and x0 such that f(x2) = f(x0). So f is not surjective.

Comment: Well, it is not injective over $\Bbb R$, not over $\Bbb Z_+$. For example, your $x_2$ could be $\pi$ or $1/2$.

Comment: I did answer the question by pointing out that only lines with slope +-1 are bijections on the integers. I've edited my answer to provide more justification for this claim.